# Wordpress Docker won't increase upload limit

Tags: wordpress, docker, wordpress-theming, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to increate the upload limit of my Dockerized Wordpress instance to 150M.

`[filename] exceeds the maximum upload size for this site.`

I have created an `uploads.ini` file and attached it by volume to the instance. Yet I still can't get the Wordpress media uploader to increase it's limit.

Docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'
services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password1
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: password1

   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     build: ./wordpress
     ports:
       - "8085:80"
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: password1
     volumes: 
       - ./uploads.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini 
volumes:
    db_data:
```

uploads.ini:

```
file_uploads = On
memory_limit = 500M
upload_max_filesize = 500M
post_max_size = 500M
max_execution_time = 600
```

Docker inspect on container:

```
[
    {
        "Id": "8edc91a51bf8480edc927de2fa5c16624ac43a7beb58c109cd771a143f67746f",
        "Created": "2017-03-15T23:47:54.480206792Z",
        "Path": "docker-entrypoint.sh",
        "Args": [
            "apache2-foreground"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 15956,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2017-03-16T17:46:30.075247017Z",
            "FinishedAt": "2017-03-16T17:46:29.700791339Z"
        },
        "Image": "sha256:cfe94722592e66629527d7fc1546174916c758c6945eb9911506077e76c4d00e",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/8edc91a51bf8480edc927de2fa5c16624ac43a7beb58c109cd771a143f67746f/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/8edc91a51bf8480edc927de2fa5c16624ac43a7beb58c109cd771a143f67746f/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/8edc91a51bf8480edc927de2fa5c16624ac43a7beb58c109cd771a143f67746f/hosts",
        "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/8edc91a51bf8480edc927de2fa5c16624ac43a7beb58c109cd771a143f67746f/8edc91a51bf8480edc927de2fa5c16624ac43a7beb58c109cd771a143f67746f-json.log",
        "Name": "/edgeofrevolt_wordpress_1",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "aufs",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "",
        "ExecIDs": [
            "8efe40659ebd3e44b17d45f1dd2aac20f12e13a4513e41520d6c2a1b1f01aa08"
        ],
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": [
                "/root/NginxDockerProxyPass/edgeofrevolt/uploads.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini:rw",
                "374db2645434a23b92074b6d95935361948397519f2d5a531986bb925ceb0f53:/var/www/html:rw"
            ],
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "edgeofrevolt_default",
            "PortBindings": {
                "80/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "8085"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "always",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": [],
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "Dns": null,
            "DnsOptions": null,
            "DnsSearch": null,
            "ExtraHosts": null,
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": null,
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 67108864,
            "Runtime": "runc",
            "ConsoleSize": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "Memory": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": null,
            "DiskQuota": 0,
            "KernelMemory": 0,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": -1,
            "OomKillDisable": false,
            "PidsLimit": 0,
            "Ulimits": null,
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Name": "aufs",
            "Data": null
        },
        "Mounts": [
            {
                "Source": "/root/NginxDockerProxyPass/edgeofrevolt/uploads.ini",
                "Destination": "/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini",
                "Mode": "rw",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            },
            {
                "Name": "374db2645434a23b92074b6d95935361948397519f2d5a531986bb925ceb0f53",
                "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/374db2645434a23b92074b6d95935361948397519f2d5a531986bb925ceb0f53/_data",
                "Destination": "/var/www/html",
                "Driver": "local",
                "Mode": "rw",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            }
        ],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "8edc91a51bf8",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "80/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "affinity:container==6797730d5702955f114fd260628b82615aa7702d0cafae7dae456b1806009437",
                "WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=db:3306",
                "WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=p0kem0n2468Y",
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "PHPIZE_DEPS=autoconf \t\tfile \t\tg++ \t\tgcc \t\tlibc-dev \t\tmake \t\tpkg-config \t\tre2c",
                "PHP_INI_DIR=/usr/local/etc/php",
                "APACHE_CONFDIR=/etc/apache2",
                "APACHE_ENVVARS=/etc/apache2/envvars",
                "PHP_EXTRA_BUILD_DEPS=apache2-dev",
                "PHP_EXTRA_CONFIGURE_ARGS=--with-apxs2",
                "PHP_CFLAGS=-fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2",
                "PHP_CPPFLAGS=-fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2",
                "PHP_LDFLAGS=-Wl,-O1 -Wl,--hash-style=both -pie",
                "GPG_KEYS=0BD78B5F97500D450838F95DFE857D9A90D90EC1 6E4F6AB321FDC07F2C332E3AC2BF0BC433CFC8B3",
                "PHP_VERSION=5.6.30",
                "PHP_URL=https://secure.php.net/get/php-5.6.30.tar.xz/from/this/mirror",
                "PHP_ASC_URL=https://secure.php.net/get/php-5.6.30.tar.xz.asc/from/this/mirror",
                "PHP_SHA256=a363185c786432f75e3c7ff956b49c3369c3f6906a6b10459f8d1ddc22f70805",
                "PHP_MD5=68753955a8964ae49064c6424f81eb3e",
                "WORDPRESS_VERSION=4.7.2",
                "WORDPRESS_SHA1=7b687f1af589c337124e6247229af209ec1d52c3"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "apache2-foreground"
            ],
            "Image": "edgeofrevolt_wordpress",
            "Volumes": {
                "/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini": {},
                "/var/www/html": {}
            },
            "WorkingDir": "/var/www/html",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "docker-entrypoint.sh"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {
                "com.docker.compose.config-hash": "da7c1855141bc762874ddd4734f2b062556a041750ff48a3cfa3954bb7dfed6c",
                "com.docker.compose.container-number": "1",
                "com.docker.compose.oneoff": "False",
                "com.docker.compose.project": "edgeofrevolt",
                "com.docker.compose.service": "wordpress",
                "com.docker.compose.version": "1.8.1"
            }
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "ceec8d1498a6988b4cc56ad10afa5cf87e0670d030460efbd26bd5ace185a375",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "80/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "8085"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/ceec8d1498a6",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "",
            "Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "",
            "IPPrefixLen": 0,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "",
            "Networks": {
                "edgeofrevolt_default": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": [
                        "wordpress",
                        "8edc91a51bf8"
                    ],
                    "NetworkID": "89bde3d402cc2fe938279c30415cc2947f92205e610dff1acba69101440b90e7",
                    "EndpointID": "916db2fab99a1637aef87aa1f05fb702fb9b6d3692bf04a9bf46bf122fe9e990",
                    "Gateway": "172.23.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.23.0.3",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:17:00:03"
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

EDIT: there was a typo in 'upload_max_filesize'

Comment: For reference, this is a continuation of an issue discussion: https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/issues/10#issuecomment-288861708

Comment: @Gant yeah I'm the latest post on that. I actually created this post to not flood that post anymore. People there have it working. Hoping one of them hits me back. I exhausted all the available options to me in that thread :/

Comment: @Gant do have anymore insight, I'm getting any help unfortunately :/

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I discovered my problem.

`docker-compose kill` will kill a container but rebuild it from a cache. Meaning no changes to my files were taking place.

Use `docker-compose up -d --build`

Comment: you could use `docker-compose up -d --build`

Answer (score 142):

it worked for me as follows:
i created `uploads.ini` alongside of `docker-compose.yml` with following lines. this is exactly how it stated in fist post.

```
file_uploads = On
memory_limit = 500M
upload_max_filesize = 500M
post_max_size = 500M
max_execution_time = 600
```

after this i added

```
volumes: 
   - ./uploads.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini
```

to my .yml file as it states in first post.

after this i had to delete the container/images (basically start from scratch):

```
docker stop [image name]
docker rm [image name]
docker image rm [image name]
```

some places i end up using ID insted of image name. name or ID basically you have to stop, remove container and image. bottom line is start from scratch with additional line in your .yml file as describe in first post. remember, you'll lose all your wp work.
now run

```
docker-compose up -d --build
```

upload limit should be increased now. i was able to upload my new bigger theme after this change. no more upload file size error. only question is if you need to increase this upload size limit in the middle of your work then how would you do this?...

Comment: careful there is also a cache and sometimes your volume will persist if you try to start from scratch again. Docker volumes are not deleted when you delete your container at least not at the time when I wrote this post. I have a few Wordpress sites up now and I've done some crazy large uploads. Read the Wordpress documentation or Apache documentation to understand the issue with doing this in the middle of development.

Comment: the uploads.ini is a good idea, but you can restart the container with just `docker-compose up -d`; you don't need to rebuild or remove running containers

Comment: This worked for me over the preferred answer. 04.10.2019

Comment: This worked, but when I connect with bash to the container and browse to /usr/local/etc/ I don't see a php folder. Why is that and how is it working?

Comment: If you are using NGINX, remember to modify default.conf file like this : 
server {
...
client_max_body_size 500M;
...
}

Answer (score 40):

I prefer to adjust .htaccess for my own workflow.
Last 2 lines are what I added

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

php_value upload_max_filesize 500M
php_value post_max_size 500M
```

then restart

```
docker-compose down --volumes
docker-compose up -d
```

Enjoy )

Comment: I didn't even have to restart the container.

Comment: This is the simple and best solution. Thanks

Comment: It works like a charm. Don't even need to restart the container

Comment: This should 100% be the correct answer; way simpler.

Answer (score 21):

Just add these two lines to then end of your .htaccess file :

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 500M
php_value post_max_size 500M
```

You don't even need to restart the container

Comment: Thank you so much. I solved this issue following your advice.

Comment: This is the easiest, cleanest route in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

### This solution solves the problem via a Dockerfile:

I modified my `docker-compose.yml` in the following way when I brushed up against the PHP file upload limit issue:

First I created `uploads.ini`:

```
file_uploads = On
memory_limit = 64M
upload_max_filesize = 64M
post_max_size = 64M
max_execution_time = 600
```

Next I created `Dockerfile-php`:

```
FROM wordpress:5.8.2
COPY ./uploads.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d
```

Finally, I added `build` config in the ***wordpress*** part of `docker-compose.yml` to reference `Dockerfile-php` which in turn referenced `uploads.ini`:

```
  wordpress:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-php
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:5.8.2
   <snippity snip>
```

Then, while in the docker-compose directory with all my files:

```
docker rm [containerName]
docker-compose build --no-cache
docker-compose up -d
```

(*I know `--no-cache`  in the `build` command above is redundant if we've already deleted the legacy container(s); just good practice to ensure we always read the latest changes)*

I was now able to successfully upload the files previously failing due to the PHP limit restriction.

Answer (score 2):

The best option would be to execute the command:

```
docker-compose down && docker-compose up -d --build
```

`docker-compose kill`, in this case the process itself is killed, this is not entirely correct.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't create an 'uploads.ini' file but an 'upload.ini' file and added it, as mentioned, alongside with the `docker-compose.yaml` file.
then I did bind it as mentioned in the docker-compose.yaml file :

```
volumes:
  - ./upload.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini
```

and then I ran `docker compose up --build` and It worked !!

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in your uploads.ini

upload_max_fileszie => upload_max_filesize

Comment: It does not apply, or maybe it was edited after your post. Anyway, this reply is out of context. Suggest to check this official guide (https://stackoverflow.com/help/article-feedback) to see expected collaboration ways

Answer (score 0):

volumes:
- ./uploads.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini

This doesn't work.
It creates an empty folder "uploads.ini". (/data/compose/17/uploads.ini/)
I create a file inside it (/data/compose/17/uploads.ini/uploads.ini) but nothing happens. It remains 2M file size limit.

Comment: This is not an answer so it doesn't belong here. Instead you can add a comment or post a new question.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32156808)

Answer (score -1):

To increase upload limit you are to add these lines to **docker-compose.yml** file to wordpress environment section:

`- PHP_POST_MAX_SIZE=150M`

`- PHP_UPLOAD_MAX_FILESIZE=150M`

`- PHP_MAX_EXECUTION_TIME=600`

and exec commands:

`> docker-compose down`

`> docker-compose up -d`

Comment: Didn't work for me. Message "The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini" is still present.

Comment: Where do you have these variables from? I don't see them in the documentation.

Answer (score -2):

The best answer is if you are just **installing/uploading** a **compress** file like xxx.zip file this error will pop up and you can not install it any plugin or theams so that you have to
go to that file in the directory and open that ***xxx.zip*** file and **delete** unnecessary file for my case there is .git file which is 1.7 MB in size i delete it and it worked just fine. Hope this will solve your problem

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I did try this, but all "excess" I could find were `locale` files (responsible for translate to other languages), but still couldn't meet the 2MB quota. So seems that this does not apply to every case