# Docker Wordpress container with custom php.ini file settings

Tags: wordpress, docker, phpmyadmin

I'm running Wordpress (and PHPMyAdmin and MySQL) in a Docker container, and I need to make a change to increase the maximum uploadable file size for PHPMyAdmin

I researched a number of solutions and found a suggestion to create a custom `uploads.ini` file and then include this file in the `docker-compose` file.

So I have this:

*uploads.ini*

```
file_uploads = On
memory_limit = 64M
upload_max_filesize = 64M
post_max_size = 64M
max_execution_time = 600
```

*docker-compose.yml*

```
version: '3'

services:
  # Database
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
    networks:
      - wpsite
  # phpmyadmin
  phpmyadmin:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password 
    networks:
      - wpsite
  # Wordpress
  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    ports:
      - '8000:80'
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - './:/var/www/html'
      - ./uploads.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
    networks:
      - wpsite
networks:
  wpsite:
volumes:
  db_data:
```

I have included the `uploads.ini` file in the `volumes` for `wordpress`

```
volumes:
      - './:/var/www/html'
      - ./uploads.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini
```

But sadly after running the `docker-compose` and opening localhost:8080 to go to PHPMyAdmin I still only have a maximum file upload size of 2m, not the 64m in my custom file

Comment: did you check that the file `/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini` exists

Comment: https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/issues/10#issuecomment-241145416

Comment: Possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42983276/wordpress-docker-wont-increase-upload-limit

Answer (score 5):

You want increase the maximum uploadable file size for PHPMyAdmin, but uploads.ini you add for your wordpress container)

add volume for phpmyadmin container and you'll be happy=)

```
# phpmyadmin
phpmyadmin:
depends_on:
  - db
image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
volumes:
 - ./uploads.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini
restart: always
ports:
  - '8080:80'
environment:
  PMA_HOST: db
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password 
networks:
  - wpsite
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the upload limit to the phpmyadmin docker container with an ENV variable

Example

```
phpmyadmin:
image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
container_name: phpmyadmin
depends_on:
  - mysql
environment:
  - UPLOAD_LIMIT=512M
  - PMA_HOST=mysql
  - PMA_PORT=3306
  - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
ports:
  - "8888:80"
```

Comment: This was the method that worked for me. You just have to stop and start the docker containers afterward. 
Please note that the syntax was slightly different in my docker-compose.yml file:
`
phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    environment:
      UPLOAD_LIMIT: 512M
      PMA_HOST: mysql
      PMA_PORT: 3306
      PMA_ARBITRARY: 1
`

Answer (score 1):

You can try to rebuild your image, but like this. 
Add this somewhere in your your Dockerfile. 
This way you would be sure its not some kind of permission trouble(which I think it is)

```
  COPY ./uploads.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42260979/1951027) you need to set absolute path to mount single file. So add a `${PWD}` before files to be mounted.

Your volume part would be like:

```
volumes:
  - ${PWD}/uploads.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini
```

Answer (score -6):

You can use this plugin for the upload max size increase

https://wordpress.org/plugins/upload-max-file-size/