# Unexpected response from the server. The file may have been uploaded successfully. Check in the Media Library or reload the page. Wordpress media

Tags: php, wordpress

When I try to upload an mp4 file with 84mb. It gives me this error

"Unexpected response from the server. The file may have been uploaded successfully. Check in the Media Library or reload the page."

SSL is activated

Comment: Good read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59915558/wordpress-unexpected-response-from-the-server-the-file-may-have-been-uploaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to adjust the values to higher numbers for larger files.

Try doing following steps:

Open Cpanel -> File manager
Click search and type 'php.ini' -> Right click this file and choose edit.

change value of following

```
memory_limit 
post_max_size 
upload_max_filesize
```

Adjust the values to higher numbers for larger files. Save and try again uploading.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem

First you need to install a file manager plugin. Open file manager, search for a file with the name: `.htaccess`

Edit this file, at the bottom add the following:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 1000M
php_value post_max_size       2000M
php_value memory_limit        3000M
php_value max_execution_time  180
php_value max_input_time      180
```

Save and close
Try uploading again, in my case worked.

I followed the instructions from this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TnI_h-QjrWo

Answer (score 0):

If you encounter such an error, I recommended you to utilize your cPanel. From your cpanel locate your WordPress media files within the cPanel interface and proceed to perform a direct upload from there. Afterward, return to your WordPress media library to search for your newly uploaded file(s), you will find the file(s) there.