# Unexpected response from the server

Tags: server, response

The file may have been uploaded successfully. Check in the Media Library or reload the page. I just did update on all of the plug ins. Can someone assist.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please consult the [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) section; it is difficult to tell whether you are describing an issue or quoting a response. Also, I encourage you to read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Please check Elias Diek answer following this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61357087

' I think my answer is too late. but I would like to post a solution for anyone still looking for a solution for this issue on WordPress running on Nginx. You should add the following directive to set the maximum allowed size in HTTP(server/location) section. '

```
client_max_body_size 10M;
```