# Wordpress Docker Image won't increase upload limit on Azure

Tags: wordpress, azure, docker, azure-web-app-service

I have a WordPress image on Azure App Service. I installed WordPress directly from the docker hub. I didn't use Docker compose. The file size of the theme I will use is large. For this reason, I want to increase the WordPress file upload limit and time. But I don't know how to do this.

Can I do it by defining a value like WP_CONFIG_EXTRA?

Answer (score 0):

As per @F1Linux [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70605853/15969858),

Try to change the `docker-compose.yml` in the following way:

- Create `uploads.ini` with below settings:

```ini
file_uploads = On  
memory_limit = 64M  
upload_max_filesize = 64M  
post_max_size = 64M  
max_execution_time = 600
```

- Create `Dockerfile-php`:

```sql
FROM wordpress:5.8.2  
COPY ./uploads.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d
```

- Add `build` config of `docker-compose.yml` which refers `Dockerfile-php` which in turn refers `uploads.ini`:

```yaml
wordpress:  
build:  
context: .  
dockerfile: Dockerfile-php  
depends_on:  
- db  
image: wordpress:5.8.2  
<snippity snip>
```

Run the docker-compose directory with all files:

```css
docker-compose down && docker-compose up -d --build
```

(**OR**) Alternatively:

Modify the Network Admin Settings to increase the value.

- Select Network Admin => Settings=> Scroll down to the `Upload Setting` section, modify the `Max upload file size` then press `Save Changes`.

Please refer [Update PHP settings](https://azureossd.github.io/2019/01/29/azure-app-service-linux-update-php-settings/) for more information.